Сборка C в .exe на линуксе | mingw tools
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    GtkWidget *window;
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_widget_show(window);
    gtk_main();
    return 0;
}

[hart@archlinux game]$ i686-w64-mingw32-gcc main.c $(pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0)
In file included from /usr/include/glib-2.0/gio/gio.h:48,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-3.0/gdk/gdkapplaunchcontext.h:28,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-3.0/gdk/gdk.h:32,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtk.h:30,
                 from main.c:1:
/usr/include/glib-2.0/gio/gcredentials.h:77:1: ошибка: неизвестное имя типа «uid_t»
   77 | uid_t            g_credentials_get_unix_user      (GCredentials    *credentials,
      | ^~~~~
/usr/include/glib-2.0/gio/gcredentials.h:81:52: ошибка: неизвестное имя типа «uid_t»; имелось в виду «pid_t»?
   81 |                                                    uid_t           uid,
      |                                                    ^~~~~
      |                                                    pid_t
[hart@archlinux game]$ micro main.c

пытался сделать кросплатформенное приложение.

Пока не понял как использовать ГТК, но в windows.h все отлично.

mingw обычно используется для кросс-компиляции под Windows. Соответственно ему нельзя подкладывать системные бибилиотеки, никаких /usr/include. gtk необходимо будет собрать этим компилятором отдельно.

Я уже понял, но спасибо. Пришел к тому, что написал свое кроссплатформенное апи. Дырявое но я его улучшаю, так что нормально
